# LUA send string by socket communication

Tags: sockets, lua

Need to send this command "sINT1 2" once to an IP address of 192.168.0.111 at port 2115

Tried some code based on my robot manual but nothing seems to work.

```
tcp.client.connect("192.168.0.111", 2115)
tcp.client.send_str_data("192.168.0.111", 2115, "sINT1 2")
```

My program gets stuck and cannot be played.

Comment: `tcp` is not a standard Lua library. You'll need to provide some more information about what you're working with.

Comment: @DarkWiiPlayer I'm working with a Robotic arm called AUBO this is the script code reference manual that I'm using. https://drive.google.com/file/d/1gqxXnQRv7oeTtg6_T9wPp9iynifnFShi/view?usp=sharing